Inserting new data into the HyperTable fails with Exception
I am trying to insert data into a hyper table using c# .net application and I am getting the error/exception:
MessageText: invalid INSERT on the root table of hypertable "_hyper_31_1083_chunk" Hint: Make sure the TimescaleDB extension has been preloaded. Where: COPY DummyDataPointMonth, line 1 File: hypertable.c Line: 1336. For added information, the table DummyDataPointMonth contains the following columns:
    "DataPointMonthId" serial NOT NULL,
    "LinkedDeviceId" int4 NOT NULL,
    "Reading" numeric(12, 4) NOT NULL,
    "Rate" int2 NOT NULL,
    "Date" date NOT NULL

and when initially I fill the table from another table, it goes good. But later, when I try to add more records into the table for the time period (date) which previously have been loaded in already for other devices, it gives the above exception (read the example below). I am not sure what is going wrong but if I disable the ts_blocker trigger, then the inserts are allowed but timescale auto generate the trigger during the creation of the hypertables and removing them causes issues so that is not a solution.
Example: Say I imported the data from another Table into DummyDataPointMonth:
ID.     DeviceId  Reading      Rate   Date
5309249 1108      25469.0000    181 2024-08-01
5309250 1110      25399.0000    181 2024-08-01
5309251 1111      25288.0000    181 2024-08-01
5309252 1112      25183.0000    181 2024-08-01
5309253 1113      24963.0000    181 2024-08-01
5309236 1114      24584.0000    181 2024-08-01
5309237 1115      24210.0000    181 2024-08-01
5309238 1116      23634.0000    181 2024-08-01
5309239 1117      23114.0000    181 2024-08-01
5309240 1118      22766.0000    181 2024-08-01

This goes good the first time. Later when I try to insert the below record into the table using the below mentioned query, it breaks with the above mentioned exception:
INSERT INTO "DummyDataPointMonth" ("DeviceId", "Reading", "Rate", "Date")
VALUES (123, 42.5, 181, '2024-08-01'); 


I have the Timescale DB: 2.14.2 and Postgres 16. Any help will be appreciated.
I can see the chunks created already and I think because the chunk for that month is already created, it does not allow me to insert a new record which should also go into the already existing chunk. I can verify that when I add a record with the date 2024-11-X, because there are no records that exist with this date, it allows the insert but later it does not allow anymore inserts for that data.
Running SELECT * FROM timescaledb_information.chunks WHERE hypertable_name = 'DummyDataPointMonth'; yields:
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1058_chunk    Date    date    2022-09-01 02:00:00.000 +0200   2022-09-08 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 16:29:37.949 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1059_chunk    Date    date    2022-09-29 02:00:00.000 +0200   2022-10-06 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 16:30:22.725 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1060_chunk    Date    date    2022-10-27 02:00:00.000 +0200   2022-11-03 01:00:00.000 +0100           false       2024-09-24 16:31:28.573 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1061_chunk    Date    date    2022-11-24 01:00:00.000 +0100   2022-12-01 01:00:00.000 +0100           false       2024-09-24 16:32:56.459 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1062_chunk    Date    date    2022-12-01 01:00:00.000 +0100   2022-12-08 01:00:00.000 +0100           false       2024-09-24 16:32:56.462 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1063_chunk    Date    date    2022-12-29 01:00:00.000 +0100   2023-01-05 01:00:00.000 +0100           false       2024-09-24 16:36:19.030 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1064_chunk    Date    date    2023-01-26 01:00:00.000 +0100   2023-02-02 01:00:00.000 +0100           false       2024-09-24 16:38:35.299 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1065_chunk    Date    date    2023-02-23 01:00:00.000 +0100   2023-03-02 01:00:00.000 +0100           false       2024-09-24 16:41:06.943 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1066_chunk    Date    date    2023-03-30 02:00:00.000 +0200   2023-04-06 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 16:44:10.192 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1067_chunk    Date    date    2023-04-27 02:00:00.000 +0200   2023-05-04 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 16:47:40.268 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1068_chunk    Date    date    2023-06-01 02:00:00.000 +0200   2023-06-08 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 16:51:30.229 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1069_chunk    Date    date    2023-06-29 02:00:00.000 +0200   2023-07-06 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 16:55:49.704 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1070_chunk    Date    date    2023-07-27 02:00:00.000 +0200   2023-08-03 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 17:00:20.642 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1071_chunk    Date    date    2023-08-31 02:00:00.000 +0200   2023-09-07 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 17:05:27.448 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1072_chunk    Date    date    2023-09-28 02:00:00.000 +0200   2023-10-05 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 17:11:04.745 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1073_chunk    Date    date    2023-10-26 02:00:00.000 +0200   2023-11-02 01:00:00.000 +0100           false       2024-09-24 17:16:52.626 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1074_chunk    Date    date    2023-11-30 01:00:00.000 +0100   2023-12-07 01:00:00.000 +0100           false       2024-09-24 17:22:04.361 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1075_chunk    Date    date    2023-12-28 01:00:00.000 +0100   2024-01-04 01:00:00.000 +0100           false       2024-09-24 17:27:39.057 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1076_chunk    Date    date    2024-02-01 01:00:00.000 +0100   2024-02-08 01:00:00.000 +0100           false       2024-09-24 17:32:50.519 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1077_chunk    Date    date    2024-02-29 01:00:00.000 +0100   2024-03-07 01:00:00.000 +0100           false       2024-09-24 17:39:06.546 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1078_chunk    Date    date    2024-03-28 01:00:00.000 +0100   2024-04-04 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 17:44:48.774 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1079_chunk    Date    date    2024-04-25 02:00:00.000 +0200   2024-05-02 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 17:52:19.419 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1080_chunk    Date    date    2024-05-30 02:00:00.000 +0200   2024-06-06 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 17:58:47.227 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1081_chunk    Date    date    2024-06-27 02:00:00.000 +0200   2024-07-04 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 18:06:56.632 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1082_chunk    Date    date    2024-08-01 02:00:00.000 +0200   2024-08-08 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 18:15:34.409 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1083_chunk    Date    date    2024-08-29 02:00:00.000 +0200   2024-09-05 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-24 18:23:43.557 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1084_chunk    Date    date    2024-09-26 02:00:00.000 +0200   2024-10-03 02:00:00.000 +0200           false       2024-09-25 13:36:45.365 +0200
public  DummyDataPointMonth _timescaledb_internal   _hyper_31_1085_chunk    Date    date    2024-10-31 01:00:00.000 +0100   2024-11-07 01:00:00.000 +0100           false       2024-09-25 14:29:41.072 +0200


Can you share reproducible DDL steps?

To me this Hint: Make sure the TimescaleDB extension has been preloaded. needs to be confirmed. Do you have shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb' in postgresql.conf?

@AdrianKlaver Yes, can confirm that the configuration exists.

Then I don't know what is happening. You might have more luck on the Timescale Forum.

It looks like your C# .NET application is trying to insert data directly into a specific chunk rather than letting TimescaleDB automatically route the data through the root hypertable, or it’s trying to insert it in a wrong place.
You can verify the following things:

Check if the insert in the code is something like this:

INSERT INTO DummyDataPointMonth ("LinkedDeviceId", "Reading", "Rate", "Date") VALUES (...);

With any references to _hyper_31_1083_chunk.

Check the output of:

SELECT * FROM timescaledb_information.hypertables WHERE hypertable_name = 'DummyDataPointMonth';

To see if everything is correct there.

Check the chunk interval created (in seconds):

SELECT h.table_name, d.interval_length / 1000000 AS chunk_time_interval_seconds
FROM _timescaledb_catalog.hypertable h
JOIN _timescaledb_catalog.dimension d ON h.id = d.hypertable_id
WHERE h.table_name = 'DummyDataPointMonth' AND d.column_name = 'Date';


Check the output of:

postgres=# \dx

and
SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name = 'timescaledb';

To see if the timescaledb extension is enabled.

You can also upgrade your TimescaleDB version which could help in some cases.

Finaly, you can verify the content of the line of this message:


COPY DummyDataPointMonth, line 1 File: hypertable.c Line: 1336

